# Running an opencd function (VideoWriter) in Debug mode and Release mode

Tags: debugging, opencv, release

I was trying to build and run the code below (Visual Studio 2013). Building is fine, but the code runs only in Debug mode, but fails in Release mode. I can see that the code stops when it tries to call the VideoWriter function, and I assume that it might be related to the file permission. But, why is it okay in Debug mode? It's a bit confusing.. Can somebody tell what's happening here or what I can further try to nail down the problem?
Thanks.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    // Get size of frames
    Size S = Size((int)cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), (int)
        cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));

    // Make a video writer object and initialize it at 30 FPS
    VideoWriter put("output.mpg", CV_FOURCC('M', 'P', 'E', 'G'), 30, S);

    if (!put.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "File could not be created for writing. Check permissions" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Video");

    // Play the video in a loop till it ends
    while (char(waitKey(1)) != 'q' && cap.isOpened())
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;
        // Check if the video is over
        if (frame.empty())
        {
            cout << "Video over" << endl;
            break;
        }
        imshow("Video", frame);
        put << frame;
    }

    return 0;
}
```